# Is there any way to emulate the behavior of a reference to a primative in JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a browser extension that runs on top of a javascript game for which the code is minified/obfuscated. Every time the game is updated, all the symbols change but the majority of the behavior remains the same. In an attempt to save myself work in the future, I started attempting to define references to the symbols used so an update would only require updating the references rather than changing every variable name throughout the code.

For objects, this method works perfectly.

```
tla.property = 4
usefullName = tla
tla.property = 5
console.log(usefullName.property) // => 5
usefullName.property = 6
console.log(tla.property) // => 6
```

However, I don't believe it's possible to create a reference to a primitive.

```
unk = 4
usefullVarName = unk
unk = 5
console.log(usefullVarName) // => 4 Desired 5
```

When researching my problem, the most common answer was to wrap the primitive in an object. This solution does not work for me since I don't control how the original unk is used throughout the game.

A friend recommended using get, which I don't fully understand, but the resulting code got me 1/2 way to my desired behavior.

```
unk = 4
usefullVarNameGetter = () => {
  return unk
}
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'usefullVarName', { get: usefullVarNameGetter});
unk = 5
console.log(usefullVarName) // => 5
usefullVarName = 6
console.log(unk) // => 5 Desired 6
```

I also started looking into proxys, however they don't seem to apply to my use case since I intend to alter the value of the original variable by altering the value of the reference.

Is there any way to make this work? Is there a better approach that I haven't thought of? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea if it fits your use case, but exporting a variable from  JavaScript modules exports the variable's binding, i.e. the variable's name and lvalue of its locatation in memory. You can import them under different names, but imports are only available using an HTTP or HTTPS URL of the exporting file - so you might be able to play a game offline if it's still cached, but typically not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't think I can apply that to my problem.

Comment: I have a solution that works. `Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'usefullName', { get: () => {return a},set: (val) => {a = val}});`

Comment: Congratulations! May I suggest that you write it up as an answer, with a description of what it does and what it's useful for, and post it? You can accept but don't get rep points from accepting your own reply.